# How to Redirect Calls to conference/or other agent using Twilio Client webRTC

Tags: javascript, php, twilio

How can I redirect active calls to conference or transfer to other agents using the Twilio Client javascript. I was trying to used jquery ajax but the transfer wont push through.

Client

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/connect", //sample only
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'CallSid': conn.parameters.CallSid
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
$response->redirect('/conference'); //sample url
print $response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In this case, you're sending an AJAX request to your server from your web page and receiving the TwiML back, so Twilio never sees the TwiML at all and the call is unaffected.

What you can do instead is, stick with the same AJAX function, sending the call sid to your server, but rather than respond with TwiML you'll need to [update the call by sending a request to the Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state). When you update a call like this, you can either change the call's state or redirect the call to a new URL with more TwiML. So, if you want to redirect a user into a conference call, you would need a URL that returned TwiML for a conference and then you'd use a call like this to redirect the call to it:

```
$sid = "{{ account_sid }}"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$call = $client->account->calls->get($_POST["CallSid"]);
$call->update(array(
  "Url" => "/conference",
  "Method" => "POST"
));
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi philnash, thank you for the response. I tried it but the agent was the one going in to the conference. The caller hangup.

Comment: Ah, then you need to get the call Sid of the other leg then. Depending on how the call was formed, the other leg will either be this call's parentCallSid, or you can find the child call by listing calls and filtering by the parentCallSid (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters). Once you find the other leg's SID, then you can redirect as described above.